# Kotlin Script Exception in BasicJvmScriptEvaluator

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-script

I am trying to use scripts in my project using Kotlin scripts. I followed the [official kotlin tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/custom-script-deps-tutorial.html) which works fine. Then I wanted to wrap my scripts into an object by setting the `constructorArgs`

```kotlin
private val config = createJvmCompilationConfigurationFromTemplate<MavenScriptDefinition>()

    fun evaluate(file: File, scope: Definition): ResultWithDiagnostics<EvaluationResult> {
        val host = BasicJvmScriptingHost()

        return host.evalWithTemplate<MavenScriptDefinition>(file.toScriptSource(), evaluation = {
            this.compilationConfiguration(config)
            this.constructorArgs(scope)
        })
    }
```

Definition is just an interface with a method `greet` that has been overwritten to print `Hello World`

This, however, results in an exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at kotlin.script.experimental.jvm.BasicJvmScriptEvaluator.evalWithConfigAndOtherScriptsResults(BasicJvmScriptEvaluator.kt:105)
```

This seems to be due to an issue inside of `BasicJvmScriptEvaluator.kt` which is a standard kotlin class.

I removed the constructor and all methods until I have just an empty object, everything didn't work, and the exception was the same.

The full code can be found [here](https://gitlab.micartey.dev/cardinal/kotlin-script-engine/-/tree/refactor/parent-object/) but keep in mind that you need to change the `Core` file to get it working as I use a custom classloader.